# Can the Pi3 use send specific audio to analog and everything else HDMI?

Tags: raspbian, audio

I have a Pi 3, currently running RetroPie 4.1.  I am wanting to keep Kodi and Retroarch using the HDMI out, but also wanting to run the python version of AlexaPi.  I want the AlexaPi application to use analog out for some smaller speakers that won't require the HDMI audio.  I'm not even sure if this is possible, but just curious what you guys thought.  Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to the Raspberry Pi flavoured corner of the Stack Exchange Network.  I haven't tested exactly how the RPi's audio output is configured so I won't post an untested solution but it seems to me that `pulseaudio` at least does seem to offer the ability of different applications to send their audio output to different destinations (and to control the levels involved with the mixing operations that are needed when multiple sources want to sink their outputs to the same destinations)...

Comment: ... What you want to know is if both the 3.5mm analogue audio (and video output on later Pis including your Pi 3B) and the HDMI output can be used simultaneously.  To that I am not sure.  However you can certainly add a low-cost USB audio sound dongle with 3.5mm connectors that you can connect to your _amplified_ (I guess that only some such dongles can directly power a pair of speakers or headphones and then amplified speakers are going to be required to boost the output power to a level that will work _passive_ or _un-amplified_) speakers.

Comment: Thanks SlySven.  If I run an aplay -l I see that both the analog and HDMI audio are both from Card:0 on the bcm2835.  I have a USB headset plugged in, that I'm using the microphone for for AlexaPi and that is Card:1.  The AlexaPi has a config to choose which hardware to output to.  I can easily change this config to make Alexa work with the USB Headphones, and all my other audio work from HDMI.  I just can't force anything to choose between the two bcm2835 options without changing it from analog to digital globally.  Seems we can only do one or the other.  I'll look for a usb sound card.  :)